# C# WinForms: On New Form Load Choose Tab Visibility

Tags: c#, windows, forms, tabcontrol

I'm having trouble with setting the visibility of a tab when a file is loaded in my application. 
When a user launches the app it displays the welcome tab, what I'm trying to do is when a user selects file -> open it loads the file in a new editor form fine but I can't seem to figure out how to make it load the form and also set the visibility of the editor tab.

```
          if (this.openEditorDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK && editForm != null)
        {
            editForm.Close();
            editForm = new EditorForm(this);
            editForm.OpenFile(this.openEditorDialog.FileName);
            editForm.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(EditorForm_Closing);
            editForm.Show();
        }
```

I've tried doing editForm.EditorTab.Show(); as well as Activecontrol = editForm.EditorTab to no avail. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to guess what that tab is doing.  Surely it should be controlled by EditorForm itself in its OpenFile() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TabControl has a `SelectedTab` property: [check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx) for that. I know I have a sample, just need to find it.

...oops, it is `SelectTab`: [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c881zk4f.aspx)

```
void SetVisibleTab(TabPage tabPage) {
   myTabControl.SelectTab(tabPage);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After your form.show command do the following:

```
            Application.DoEvents();
        EditorTab.Focus();
```

Comment: Because it allow the .Show method to complete before attempting focus.  If you don't do something to allow .show to complete the .focus will not work reliably.  This is one of the very few instances that DoEvents is good for.  Causes the message pump on the window to process outstanding messages before continuing.

Comment: You don't need to use `.Focus()` - making `.DoEvents()` unnecessary.

Comment: Without the .Focus() how do you intend on changing the focused control?  Actually in this instance, it would likely be the first control on the tab to set focus to, but who know what the actual intent of the jonalodev is.

Comment: "*when a user selects file -> open it loads the file in a new editor...make it load the form and also set the visibility of the editor tab.*" ...seems fairly obvious that the OP wants to set visibility on a TabPage ... which is why we have the `SelectTab(...)` method available.